# GitLab Object Storage configuration

Tags: azure, gitlab

I try to configure GitLab object storage. I'm using docker-compose and my configuration is taken from here: [object-storage-gitlab](https://mec-gitlab.liteon.com/gitlab/help/administration/object_storage.md)

```bash
gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = {
  'provider' => 'AzureRM',
  'azure_storage_account_name' => '<AZURE STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>',
  'azure_storage_access_key' => '<AZURE STORAGE ACCESS KEY>',
  'azure_storage_domain' => '<AZURE STORAGE DOMAIN>',
}
```

and when I try to send an attachment I got this error:

```bash
Fog::AzureRM::CustomAzureCoreHttpError (AuthorizationFailure (403): This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:26f7468a-801e-0013-5bd4-d2e361000000
Time:2023-08-19T19:35:37.8519239Z):
```

My blob object storage is configured as private but I'm using Access Key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your storage account you have enabled public access from all the servers or at-least the [**IP address**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/webhooks.html#allow-requests-to-the-local-network-from-webhooks-and-integrations) in which your Gitlab server is running.

[image]

[image]

In addition to this the account or service principal you're using for storage account authentication should have atleast - **Storage Blob Data Owner** or **Storage Blob Data Contriibutor** role assigned to the user authenticating with Gitlab.

[image]

**My gitlab.rb file:-**

```rb
gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = {
 'provider'  => 'AzureRM',
 'azure_storage_account_name'  => 'siliconstrg09',
 'azure_storage_access_key'  => 'xxxxxgHvKF80G6qrmRC/24FIOmj6MXdYZgyjB1xxxxx==',
 'azure_storage_domain'  => 'blob.core.windows.net'
}
```

**My **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:-**

```yaml
variables:
 AZURE_CLIENT_ID:  xxxxxx35cb
 AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET:  xxxxxxx313-CS0ifbLE
 AZURE_TENANT_ID:  xxxxxx592395
 AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME:  xxxxx
stages:
 -  configure
configure_gitlab:
 stage:  configure
 script:
 -  echo  "Copying gitlab.rb configuration"
 -  cp  gitlab.rb  /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
 -  gitlab-ctl  reconfigure
 only:
 -  master
```

Allow outbound request for Azure blob hostname by referring the document [**here**](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/advanced/external-object-storage/#troubleshooting).